# Not able to play live video through ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am using ExoPlayer for playing video in Android,. We are using the ExoPlayer for playing mp4 and live videos. But sometime we are getting the exception described below.

```
> 12-01 14:15:09.388 12080-12517/com.mse.monumentalsnetwork
> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>                                                                                    com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException:
> Input does not start with the #EXTM3U header.
>                                                                                        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:119)
>                                                                                        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.playlist.HlsPlaylistParser.parse(HlsPlaylistParser.java:43)
>                                                                                        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:115)
>                                                                                        at
> com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
>                                                                                        at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                        at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So Please help me on it.

Comment: Looks like an error parsing the .m3u playlist file at the url (presuming you're using m3u format). Is this only happening on the live stream?

Comment: post your playlist you are using

Comment: @pskink playlist means the url which i am playing ?

Comment: i mean [extended m3u](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U#Extended_M3U) playlist

Comment: @nitintyagi Did you find a solution to the issue?

Comment: Any solution found ?

Comment: @NibinSalim yes, The issue was with HLS url. Exoplayer was not able to parse that url. So check your url.

Comment: Any solution found ?

Answer (score 5):

The error indicates that you are using a HlsMediaSource while you want to play an MP4 file. It fails to parse the HLS manifest.

You need to use an ExtractorMediaSource for playing MP4:

```
DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSource = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
    Util.getUserAgent(this, "your-user-agent"));
ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSource)
    .createMediaSource(uri, null, null);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

The demo application of ExoPlayer has a [createMediaSource](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L360) method which demonstrates the creation of the available media sources.

Comment: Am 100% sure. we are using m3u8 file for playing.

Comment: @Ramkailash, did you find a solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL. It could be that your URL contains a blank space, which you can replace like this:

```
String StringName= "Your URL".replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using different format like

> **format=mpd-time-csf** then i changed it to
> **format=m3u8-aapl** then i was able to play azure streaming video.

Referece: [HLS Dynamic packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-dynamic-packaging-concept#hls-dynamic-packaging)